# Why every production deployment has need to clear the browser cache

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, caching

Every new production deployment need to clear cache in react js.

Comment: add details on-  how you deploy your application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you access a web site like

```
http:// mysite.com/index.html
```

if a cached copy of the file `index.html` is present on the browser cache it returns that copy. Unluckly that copy has pointers to the old javascript and css files that are already cached on the browser. So also if your javascript files changed their names you will always get the old cached copy with the old name.

You can solve this problem informing the browser that the `index.html` must not be cached. Otherwyse you need to manually clear the cache. This can be done adding

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
```

to your index.html.